# Spinnaker Jenkins Integration unable to fetch jobs from Jenkins

Tags: exception, jenkins, spinnaker

We have completed all the steps as described in the hello-spinnaker example below.We have used the AWS spinnaker image to directly configure spinnaker in AWS.

www.spinnaker.io/docs/hello-spinnaker.

I am trying to create a sample pipeline as noted in the above example.But while I create trigger in the first step and select jenkins ,the jobs are not getting populated and am getting below error in browser.

GET http://localhost:8084/v2/builds/Jenkins/jobs 429 (Too Many Requests)

The actual issue looks like while retrofit is trying to map the  response from jenkins getjobs into the JobList class its finding an attribute _class in jenkins response xml and which is not present in JobList groovy class.Below is how we tried finding the issue

1)Login to AWS Spinnaker instance

2)Gate service is exposed at port 8084.
curl http://localhost:8084/v2/builds/Jenkins/jobs.

```
{"failureCause":"retrofit.RetrofitError: 429 Too Many Requests","error":"Too Many Requests","message":"429 Too Many Requests","status":429,"url":"http://localhost:8088/jobs/Jenkins","timestamp":1462793944530}
```

3)Igor service is exposed at port 8088.
curl http://localhost:8088/jobs/Jenkins

```
{"fallbackException":"java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No fallback available.","failureType":"COMMAND_EXCEPTION","failureCause":"retrofit.converter.ConversionException: org.simpleframework.xml.core.AttributeException: Attribute '_class' does not have a match in class com.netflix.spinnaker.igor.jenkins.client.model.JobList at line 1","error":"Hystrix Failure","message":"jenkins-Jenkins-getJobs failed and no fallback available.","status":429,"timestamp":1462793896853}
```

When I check in the igor logs,there are few exceptions which are occuring during the getprojects by jenkins poll

```
Caused by: retrofit.converter.ConversionException: org.simpleframework.xml.core.AttributeException: Attribute '_class' does not have a match in class com.netflix.spinnaker.igor.jenkins.client.model.ProjectsList at line 2
at retrofit.converter.SimpleXMLConverter.fromBody(SimpleXMLConverter.java:38)
at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:367)
... 39 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.simpleframework.xml.core.AttributeException: Attribute '_class' does not have a match in class com.netflix.spinnaker.igor.jenkins.client.model.ProjectsList at line 2
```

4)Connect to jenkins and get the jobs as its being done in spinnaker code https://github.com/spinnaker/igor/blob/master/igor-web/src/main/groovy/com/netflix/spinnaker/igor/jenkins/client/JenkinsClient.groovy

resp = requests.get('http://jenkinserverip:8080/api/xml?tree=jobs[name,jobs[name,jobs[name,jobs[name,jobs[name,jobs[name,jobs[name,jobs[name,jobs[name,jobs[name]]]]]]]]]]',auth=('admin','password'))
print resp.text

```
<hudson _class='hudson.model.Hudson'><job _class='hudson.model.FreeStyleProject'><name>Hello Build</name></job><job _class='hudson.model.FreeStyleProject'><name>Hello Poll</name></job></hudson>
```

So as the jenkins response is having the _class attribute ,retrofit is throwing an error at this line http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.squareup.retrofit/retrofit/1.9.0/retrofit/RestAdapter.java#383

I wanted to see how can we quickly fix this as it looks like some version in compatibility of jenkins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a bug around the jenkins api in later version. I believe 2.2 is the last compatible version, we run 1.6 internally.

Comment: this should be fixed if you pull the latest igor debian

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing a similar issue in spinnaker 1.8.5. I had to reformat the jenkins url from `myjenkins.server.com:8080` to `http://myjenkins.server.com/` and it corrected the issue.